# Rename excel file with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating an excel file from nothing, adding content and saving it. I want to rename the excel file once I saved it, using VBA code. The file I want to rename isn't the same file in which I'm writing the code.

Currently I'm trying to do it this way (this is a snippet of my code, just to show how I'm saving the file):

```
    Dim workbook1 As Workbook
    Dim name As String, lastcell As String
    Dim oldname As String, newname As String

    Set workbook1 = Application.Workbooks.Add

    name = "financial report - "

    workbook1.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & name & ".xlsx"    
    
    'lastcell has a date that I want in my new title
    lastcell = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Text

    oldname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & name & ".xlsx"
    newname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & name & lastcell & ".xlsx"

    Name oldname As newname
```

But when I run it I get this:

[image: error]

The value in my `lastcell` variable is supposed to be in a date format like this `dd/mm/yyyy`. The exact cell I'm trying to copy and use as part of the name of my new excel is `05/02/2021`.

The value in name by the end of the sub should be `financial report - 05/02/2021`.

I'm gonna be surprised if this hasn't been asked before. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong or have any recomendations for my code?

Comment: When you save a  workbook file with `SaveAs`, it stays open. As long as it's open, you cannot move, delete or rename it. But why don't you store it with the corrent name directly?

Comment: Wish I could. Whenever I try to save it that way I get a '1004' error telling me there are several possible reasons for it.

Comment: @Sena But that's the only way, you probably asked the wrong question then (see [What is the x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). Because as FunThomas said as long as it is open you cannot rename it and when you close it your VBA stops (and you cannot rename it with VBA anymore). So the correct way is the answer below.

Comment: Add `Debug.Print oldname` and `Debug.Print newname` and see what the output looks like.  Is the first an existing file, and is the second a valid file name?  If `lastcell` has a date, is it formatted in a way that it would be valid as part of a file name?

Comment: [Just tested it](https://imgur.com/a/55gdRQW), and it looks like a valid name - actually exactly like it was supposed to be if it worked. I used ```VarType``` to see what was the type of ```lastcell```'s value and it was a string. I'm not sure what else I could do.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I'm sure I could do better with my choice of words. But I'm not gonna get any closer to finding out what my problem is by asking again or rewriting the question, it took the whole morning to write it down. I'm trying out what the other users are recommending and if none of the recommendations work out I'll delete, edit or rewrite the question, but while there's people trying to help me I would like to keep working on this if that doesn't go against the rules. Thank you!

Comment: @Sena please edit your question and add the **actual value** of the variable `lastcell` and `name`. If we know the real values it is much easier to help, there might be not allowed characters or something like that in your data. Also your code should somehow throw an error because after `Dim workbook1 As Workbook` the variable `workbook1` is not set to any value and is `Nothing` then you run `workbook1.SaveAs` which cannot work because you cannot save `Nothing`. So the code you show cannot be what you actual have, at least it's not a complete example see [mcve].

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Will do. Thanks!

Comment: @Pᴇʜ the code isn't complete as I said before. It doesn't give me an error because I'm creating it at the beginning and only close to the end I save it. I'm adding it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a date value which can work as part of a filename:

```
lastcell = Format(Range("A1").End(xlDown),"yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.savecopyas

```
workbook1.SaveCopyAs newname
```

Comment: Hello Johnniel, I tried your code but I'm getting the run-time error '1004' . It says there are several possible reasons for it. either 'the file name or path does not exist' (which I'm pretty sure it's not the case), 'the file is being used by another program' or 'the workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook'. If I'm saving it as a copy so it couldn't be the second one.

Comment: 1004 covers all sorts of invalid filename type of stuff in my experience, my guess is it means most likely you are trying to save a workbok with macros as an `.xlsx` file, so look at the definition of variable `workbook1` i'd suggest

Comment: That's not it, the file I'm trying to save doesn't have macros. I'm going to keep looking, thanks a lot.

Comment: can you post a screen shot of the error box/text in the message box and the value of `newname` that cause it to fail? thanks

Comment: @Sena: Please show us how `lastcell` string looks. It  maybe has some illegal characters (/, \ etc.)...

Comment: @JohnnieL [here it is](https://imgur.com/a/55gdRQW). And here's the [error message](https://imgur.com/a/EaHmFrs).

Comment: @FaneDuru it does have "\", since it's a string taken from a cell with a date format (dd/mm/yyyy). could that be it?

Comment: The forward  slash is blowing it up - its an illegal character in this context. If last cell is always going to be a date just do something like `format(lastcell, "yyyy-mm-dd")`

Comment: @Sena: Yes, most probably, this is the reason. Try please, `lastcell = Format(Range("A1").End(xlDown).Text, "dd_mm_yyyy")`.

Comment: @JohnnieL I tried yours and FaneDuru's but sadly I'm still getting the error '75' same as the one in the beginning. Gonna keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

There you have your issue `05/02/2021` cannot be part of the file name as a slash `/` is not allowed in file names. Slash and backslash are considered to be path seperators.

Try the following: Make sure the variables are declared properly as below, to ensure the date is read as numerical date and not as some text that cannot be formatted.

```
Dim Name As String    
Name = "financial report - "

Dim ReportDate As Date
ReportDate = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Value 'make sure you read the `.Value` not `.Text`

workbook1.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Name & ".xlsx"    
workbook1.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Name & Format$(ReportDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") ".xlsx"
```

Also use `.SaveAs` to save the original workbook and `.SaveCopyAs` to save the copy with the date attached.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. I had two main issues: 1) the date format and 2)  the open workbook (path/file access error). I'm gonna go with Tim's answer because it looks more like the code I did and that worked. But thank you for your help, actually for everybody's help!